# mongodb: cursor iteration wait for update to finish

Tags: mongodb

I have a cursor from a find query to get all people:

```
var cursor = db.people.find({ <query> });
```

And then I iterate though each document and issue an update query for each document:

```
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    var obj = cursor.next();

    // do some processing ...
    db.people.update({ _id: obj._id}, { <set some fields> })
}
```

It seems the updates are fired asynchronously and when the while loop finishes, so does this script and some updates are not finished. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

What API driver are you using?

In the pymongo driver there is something called [WriteConcern](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/write_concern.html#pymongo.write_concern.WriteConcern)
If it is not set to `0` (in other words: if it is not disabled), it should wait for the write to be completed before returning.

In your debugging efforts you could also check the result of the update call.